# Words are not shown correctly using `Imap_parser`

Tags: php

I have a `PHP` code that accesses an email inbox using `Imap_parser`. However, the text output has strange characters:

```
    // include Imap_parser class
    include_once ('lib/Imap_parser.php');
    
    // create Imap_parser Object
    $ email = new Imap_parser();
    
    // date
    $ data = array (
    // email account
    'email' => array (
    'hostname' => '{imap.hostinger.com.br:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX',
    'username' => 'mail@my_email.ml',
    'password' => 'password'
    ),
    // inbox pagination
    'pagination' => array (
    'sort' => 'DESC', // or ASC
    'limit' => 10,
    'offset' => 0
    )
    );
    
    // get inbox. Array
    $ result = $ email-> inbox ($data);
    $newCode = json_encode($result);
```

The output of the `$newCode` variable is:

`Confirm=C3=A7=C3=A3o p=C3=A1gina n=C3=A3o`

The correct output would be:

`Confirmação página não`

That is, the characters `ç`, `á` and `ã` are not being displayed correctly.

Comment: Maybe problem is with unicode. You can try using:`utf8_encode(utf8_decode($string))`.

Comment: There is also a UTF-8 function that is specific to IMAP. I have no idea if it will help you but the fact that it exists tells me to look in that direction. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-utf8.php

Comment: Solved! Thank you.